# DB is empty, but PDO execute returns bool(True)

Tags: php, pdo

I wanna make login to school system for students and teachers.

```
    $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `teachers` WHERE `username` = :username");
    $result = $query->execute(array(
    ":username" => $username));

    if($result) {
       $_SESSION["username"]["who"] = array($username, "teacher");
       echo("<script>location.href = 'home.php';</script>");
    } else {
       $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `username`, `password` FROM `students` WHERE `username` = :username");
       $result = $query->execute(array(
       ":username" => $username));

       if($result) {
          $_SESSION["username"]["who"] = array($username, "student");
          echo("<script>location.href = 'home.php';</script>");
       } else {
          echo("<script>alert('Error.'); location.href = 'index.php';</script>");
       }
    }
```

I have only one username in my students database.
But If I can try login with random username, I every get $result = True.
Why is $result true, when the tables of teachers are empty?

Comment: Because in your code $result currently contains wether the query went well or not.  You need to fetch your data after executing the query. Then you can test if there were any results or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result of execution is unfetched statement.

I recommend to use [fetchObject](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php):

```
try {
  $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT 1 as `exists` FROM `teachers` WHERE `username` = :username LIMIT 1");
  $statement->execute([":username" => $username]);

  $teacher = $statement->fetchObject();

  if ($teacher) {
    // success here
    $_SESSION['user'] = ['username' => $username, 'role' => 'teacher'];

    session_write_close(); // gracefully closing session
    header('Location: /home.php');
    exit(0);
  }
  throw new Exception('User not found');
}
catch (Exception $exception) {
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Is exist a simpler solution? Or I have to do this?

Comment: Whatever You use in SQL query part it's result should be fetched

Comment: For example I'm returning 1 in select just to make sure that it will return a row

Comment: @num8er Correct if I'm wrong but `$query` is statement, prepare returns statement, but `$statement` is boolean `execute` on statement returns boolean, so `fetchObject` on `$statement` would result in error? And `execute` would always return true if there is nothing wrong with query, so empty result would return true as there is nothing wrong with that, you would just need to check if fetch on statement (`$query`) is or isn't empty.

Comment: @Mr_KoKa prepare returns prepared for execution query, execute returns a statement (not boolean) and because it keeps a data it passes if() since not falsy, fetch returns parsed raw data from statement and returns object or array of requested row. I'm not using php with pdo, technically I named that vars `query`, since I don't like mutating new variables. Better read official manual for what returns in some conditions. I'm ORM, ODM user (

Comment: @Mr_KoKa btw result in question does not return True, I don't know how J.Doe dumped that fact ))) maybe by doing: `if($result){` he came to idea that it's exectly True.

Comment: @num8er I'm only trying to point out that PDO::prepare returns PDOStatement, and PDOStatement::execute returns boolean, so in your example `$statement` is boolean and doing `$statement->fetchObject()` will result in exception. Or there is something I'm not aware of.

Comment: @Mr_KoKa it's impossible to do: `true->fetchObject()` I'm saying the owner of question is just guessing that it's True, False (:

Comment: @Mr_KoKa You should ask J.Doe how he came to that idea that $result === true  (:

Comment: @num8er query looks correct then it may be true, it may be false but, looking at PHP documentation, it will never be PDOStatement, so I have no problem with $result being true as PDOStatement::execute result, for me more questionable is your `$statement` being a PDOStatemen  as PDOStatement::execute result.

Comment: @num8er I'm not saying that PDOStatement has no fetchObject member function, I'm telling you that your `$statement` variable is not of type PDOStatement but boolean, so you're trying to call fetchObject member function on boolean primitive type. You said earlier that "execute returns a statement" but it doesn't, it returns boolean according to documentation http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: @Mr_KoKa, oh seems like was writing from phone (: did not mentioned the variable that I'm operating. btw You could fix my answer than downvoting, no? :D

Comment: @Mr_KoKa thank You for being patient and fixing my answer, really appreciate it